# LinkedIn iOS SDK does not import frameworks

Tags: ios, linkedin-api

The LinkedIn SDK for iOS 1.0.6 does not import the required frameworks and so fails to compile in my Swift project. The only solution I've been able to find is to type in the missing imports.

Answer (score -1):

Third party SDK's that require iOS frameworks always require you to add those frameworks. Integration instructions for most 3rd party SDK's tend to look like this:

1. Drop our SDK into your project.
2. Add the following frameworks to your project: Foundation, CoreGraphics, etc.
3. ...

Comment: This is not the problem. My App does link against those frameworks. The problem is that the framework headers do not import the required frameworks.